# Eval doesnt rendered in a href tag

Tags: .net

```
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptrCategories" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <li>
                         <a href='~/category/<%# Eval("NormalizedProductCategory") %>' runat="server"><%# Eval("ProductCategoryName")%></a></li>                   
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

When the href part is rendered by server, it is shown in client part something like below. The first eval part

```
<a href="../../category/%3C%25#%20Eval(%22NormalizedProductCategory%22)%20%25%3E">Shoes</a>
```

Whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat=server NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NormalizedProductCategory", "~/category/{0}") %>'>Name</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: How can this be the answer. Does this even work? I thought that code blocks do not work on runat="server" controls. Or is that only limited to code blocks within the head of a page?

Answer (score 1):

Code nuggets don't always work in runat="server"  controls.

If you want to do this, remove the runat="server" or move all your code to the code-behind by using it's ASP.NET counterpart

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink" runat=server />
```

Code behind within ItemDataBound:

```
HyperLink.NavigateUrl = this.ResolveUrl("~/category/" + dataItem.NormalizedProductCategory);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to this

```
<a id="A1" href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~") %>category/<%#Eval("NormalizedProductCategory") %>'><%# Eval("ProductCategoryName")%></a>
```

Notice that you have to remove the `runat="server"` for this